# Why can I not use a constexpr global variable to initialize a constexpr reference type?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

constexpr int r =100;
int main()
{
    constexpr int &k = r ;
    cout << k << endl;
}
```

Compiling this code gives "error: binding ‘const int’ to reference of type ‘int&’ discards qualifiers" at compile time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compile adding `const` after `int`.

```
constexpr int const & k = r ;
// ...........^^^^^
```

The problem is that `constepxr` implies `const`, so when you define `r`

```
constexpr int r =100;
```

you define `constexpr` as an `int const` value (also take into account that `const` is applied to the type on the left; on the right only if there isn't a type on the left; so `const int` and `int const` are the same thing).

But your `k`

```
constexpr int & k = r ;
```

isn't a `const` (implied by `constexpr`) reference to an `int const` but only a `const` reference to an `int`.

And you can't initialize a reference to an `int` variable with an `int const` value.

You can solve the error by making `k` a `const` reference to an `int const`.

Comment: Thank you max66 . I am relatively new to C++ but as far as i understand constexpr are implicitly const .  I understand once we define a constexpr on pointer its basically top-level const i.e pointer it self is const pointer and not pointer to const . For a reference type isnt declaring it as a constexpr would implicily mean that its const i.e reference to a const ( int in this case ? )

Comment: @praveen It is a constexpr reference to a non-const int, which makes at least some sense.  You cannot have a constexpr non-const value.  As an exampe, `template<int & x>struct foo{foo(){++x;}};` is a type that increments some constexpr-located int, but that int does not have a constexpr value.  The reference is constexpr; the value is not.